# Method defined in different class not found in program class using delegate

Tags: c#, delegates, access-modifiers

I have added the following class to my project

```
delegate int NumberChanger(int n);

namespace lesson02
{
    class Testdelegate
    {
        static int num = 10;
        public static int AddNum(int p)
        {
            num += p;
            return num;
        }

        public static int MultNum(int q)
        {
            num *= q;
            return num;
        }

        public static int getNum()
        {
            return num;
        }
    }    
}
```

And in my program class under the main method I am trying to create an object of the delegate and assign the method AddNum to it:

```
NumberChanger nc1 = new NumberChanger(AddNum);
```

But the AddNum method is not recognized in this class and I get the error message: CS0103  C# The name does not exist in the current context

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `new NumberChanger(lesson02.Testdelegate.AddNum);`?

Comment: That's worked! But why does the whole name have to be given when the method is public? In the example that I'm following the syntax is exactly the same as above. Do I need to reference classes to other classes or something? Would adding a using lesson02 at the top help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reference the class when making a reference to a static method in a different class. Thus, from (I presume) `Program.Main`, you should reference `Testdelegate.AddNum`. EDIT: This presumes you have a `using lesson02;` reference at the top of your file, or `Program` exists within the `lesson02` or a nested namespace.

Alternatively, if you make multiple reference to static `Testdelegate` members, you can use a `static using` (as of C# 6):

```
using static lesson02.Testdelegate;
```

Comment: Not a problem, but do keep in mind simple "thank you comments" are considered chatty - give some rep or mark answers to your questions as correct conveys the same

Comment: I know, but I have to wait a certain amount of time before I can pick your answer, don't worry.